# What relationship do two adjunctions imply?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Suppose we have three categories $A,B,C$, and we have an adjunction between $A$ and $C$ and we also have another adjunction bewteen $B$ and $C$.  What relationship does this imply between $A$ and $B$?  Does this imply equivalence of the categories?  Does it give a way to compute an adjunction between $A$ and $B$?

There is a question about left and right.  I am assuming that the composition of the functors in the adjunction between $A$ and $C$ generate a monad at $C$.  Likewise, the composition of the functors in the adjunction between $B$ and $C$ generate a monad at $C$.  I think this answers questions about left and right.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "an adjunction between $A$ and $C$"? Do you mean a left adjoint $A\to C$? A right adjoint?

Comment: Your condition on monads means that $A\to C$ and $B\to C$ are the right adjoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't imply very much at all.  For instance, if $C$ is the terminal category, a left adjoint to the unique functor $A\to C$ is any functor $C\to A$ which sends the object of $C$ to an initial object of $A$.  So to say that there are right adjoint functors $A\to C$ and $B\to C$ just means that $A$ and $B$ both have initial objects.  That certainly doesn't imply $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, and doesn't even imply there exists any adjunction between $A$ and $B$.

One thing it does imply is that the nerves of $A$ and $B$ are homotopy equivalent, since the nerve of any adjoint functor is a homotopy equivalence.  But this is a very weak condition (indeed, the nerve of any category with an initial or terminal object is contractible).